# How to link two sentences?

Tags: creative-writing, style, technique, structure, word-choice

I have the following sentences:

> Anyone can use stock footage.

and

> Only you know how to use it correctly.

I am wondering if it makes sense to combine them as such

> Anyone can use stock footage, only you know how to use it correctly.

I am implying that even though these stock footage may be free it still takes talent to select the right one and put them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You should add a *but* after the comma

> Anyone can use stock footage, **but** only you know how to use it correctly.

Reading a *but* basically makes people ignore most of what has been said before and focus their attention on what is being said after the *but*. This way you can emphasize that while anyone can use the footage it takes someone with a certain amount of experience in the specific domain or talent to use the footage correctly or efficiently.